# Symfony 4 - How can I print form input on other controller page?

Tags: symfony, request, symfony-forms, symfony4

In symfony 4, I have a form with an input that name of input is `form[phone]`.

```
<input id="phone" class="phone-input" type="text" name="form[phone]" />
```

Now when I click submit form and go to action path, when code is :

```
$phone = $request->request->all();
dump($phone);die();
```

Print this :

```
array:1 [▼
  "form" => array:3 [▼
    "phone" => "phone-value"
    "submit" => ""
    "_token" => "qiYeKA32Sw1FXKoTHbW5TkbNFXpo7KWnDejwEGEqGxo"
  ]
]
```

But when I use this code:

```
$phone = $request->request->get('form[phone]');
dump($phone);die();
```

Print this:

```
null
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is works .for print value the phone

```
  $phone2 = $request->request->get('form');
        $phone2 = $phone2['phone'];
        dump($phone2);die();
```

OR

```
  $phone2 = $request->request->get('form')['phone'];
            dump($phone2);die();
```

**Update answer**

I guess you created a form something like this

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        // ...
        ->getForm();
```

You must use object **form**  then call **handleRequest()** method, for handle form submissions:

```
 $form->handleRequest($request);
 $phone = $form->get('phone')->getData()
 dump($phone);die();
```

Comment: I don't know why you want do it .. ..But it is work .for this problem.

Comment: I want input value in my variable and use that but when I use this code just give me NULL

Comment: Are you sure this code does not print the phone  ->>> $phone2 = $request->request->get('form');
        $phone2 = $phone2['phone'];
        dump($phone2);die();

Comment: This code is true and worked. But for what I can't use " $phone = $request->request->get('form[phone]'); " directly?

Comment: Is That Clear. because it is that two dimensional array.if you want to use directly use  of this code. $phone =$request->request->get('form')['phone'];